# R: selective fill of a column from another

Tags: r

I have two dataframes with same column names, but different lengths.   Example:

```
sf<-data.frame(a=c(1,5,9),b=c(2,6,4))  
sf  
  a b  
1 1 2  
2 5 6  
3 9 4  



lf<-data.frame(a=1:10,b=rep(0,10))  
lf  
    a b  
1   1 0  
2   2 0  
3   3 0  
4   4 0  
5   5 0  
6   6 0  
7   7 0  
8   8 0  
9   9 0  
10 10 0
```

I would like to fill in values of `lf$b` with values in `sf$b` where their `a` columns are identical (i.e. where `sf$a` equals `lf$a`). Thus, the result should be:

```
    a b  
1   1 2  
2   2 0  
3   3 0  
4   4 0  
5   5 6  
6   6 0  
7   7 0  
8   8 0  
9   9 4  
10 10 0
```

Is there a quick way to do this in R?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean for `sf$a` to refer to the row index of `lf`, then the following should work:

```
lf[sf$a, ]$b = sf$b
```

However, if you mean to update rows in `lf` where `lf$a` matches `sf$a`, then you can do something like:

```
lf[lf$a %in% sf$a, ]$b = sf$b
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(sf),a)[lf][is.na(b), b:=i.b][, i.b:=NULL][]
#      a b
#  1:  1 2
#  2:  2 0
#  3:  3 0
#  4:  4 0
#  5:  5 6
#  6:  6 0
#  7:  7 0
#  8:  8 0
#  9:  9 4
# 10: 10 0
```

Or a `base R` option

```
transform(merge(lf, sf, by='a', all=TRUE), b= ifelse(is.na(b.y),
                     b.x,b.y))[-c(2:3)]
```

Comment: This is a very interesting technique as well. More general as well. Thanks.

Comment: @AsifShakeel Thanks for the comments.  The data.table option should be very fast on big datasets.